# Updating a jump links href on click

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to update a jump links href on click. I set the initial jump link to something like this:

```
<a href="#2" id="next">Next</a>
```

Then I use a little JavaScript to update the href onclick:

```
var jump = this.href.match(/\#\d+$/)[0];
var num = parseInt(jump.substr(1, jump.length), 10);
var newNum = num + 1;

document.getElementById('next').href = '#' + num;
```

For some reason, when I click the jump link the first time, it takes me to #3 (instead of the expected #2). If I change the href in the HTML to #1, it will take me to #2, which seems counter intuitive. I guess my question is, is the jump happening after the href gets updated by JavaScript (it appears to be)? And how can I get it to jump first, then update the href?

(Also, I'm using addEventListener() to trigger the click).

Comment: can you tell me what is 'jump'?  and where is the part of code that causes the jump to the new location?

Comment: Opps. Typo. `var link` should have been `var jump`. Updated. The jump itself should just be a standard jump link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var jump = this.href.match(/\#\d+$/)[0];
var num = parseInt(jump.substr(1, jump.length), 10);
var newNum = num + 1;

setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById('next').href = '#' + newNum;
});
```

Small refactoring:

```
var num = parseInt(this.href.split('#').pop(), 10);
var a = this;

setTimeout(function() {
    a.href = '#' + (num + 1);
});
```

Comment: That seems to have done the trick. Thanks. I guess this delays the update of the href?

Comment: Yes, more properly include the 1ms argument for explicitness. Doing a setTimeout of 1ms will clear the current calling stack. In this case, waiting until the current call stack clears also includes waiting until the "jumping" ends. Here's a good read: http://ejohn.org/blog/accuracy-of-javascript-time/

Answer (score 0):

the problem you are having is most likely because the jump is happening before the event is triggered, as you guessed, and this is causing `this` to be the new link, you can check it with a `console.log(this)`, a suggestion in this case will be to use `event.preventDefault();` on the event, this will not make the link work and your code will run first.
and just to make sure, you add the prevention in your event listener like this:

```
something.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();}, false)
```